# Dynamically created dropdown doesn't give correct value

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a strange problem. I have a list of `confectionoptions`. Each of these `confectionoptions` has a property which contains a list of options that can be set. If this option has the value true in its property `IsSelected` then I know this is the one.

Here is my html, if I change a value I only get the total object it self! I need the choosenvalue, how do I do this? I already tryed this with an extra knockout observable property which I set with value but this causes problems I don't want (that's why it's a problem)

```
<div>
    <div class="content" data-bind="visible: (InstoreConfectionOptions().length > 0)">
        <h3 data-bind="visible: (InstoreConfectionOptions().length > 0)">
            <span class="clean">Instore confectie opties</span>
        </h3>

        <span data-bind="foreach: InstoreConfectionOptions">
            <h4 data-bind="text: Name + ':'"></h4>
            <select data-bind="foreach: Options, 
                               event: { change: $root.SetInstoreOption }">
                <option data-bind="text: Name"></option>
            </select>
            @*<select data-bind="options: Options, 
                                 optionsText: 'Name', 
                                 value: $root.testtest ">
              </select>*@
            @*<select data-bind="//options: Options, optionsText: 'Name', event:{change: function(){ $root.SetInstoreOption($data) } }">
              </select>*@
            @*<select data-bind="options: Options, 
                                 optionsText: 'Name', 
                                 event: { change: $root.SetInstoreOption }">
              </select>*@
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my JS I want the choosen value, not the whole stuff just the choosen value. How do I do this?

```
self.SetInstoreOption = function(options) {
        for (var i = 0; i < options.Options.length; i++) {
            if (options.Options[i].Selected) {
                setOptionValue(options.Options[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your binding like this (like in your example):

```
<select data-bind="options: Options, 
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   value: $root.testtest ">
</select>
```

It means:

- the `select` will be populated with the objects inside `Options` (say it is `obj`)
- the `option`s tags will have `obj.Name` as text
- when you select an `option`, the observable `$root.testtest` will be set to `obj`

So you can get your selected object with `$root.testtest()`.

Check the **[documentation here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example-3-drop-down-list-representing-arbitrary-javascript-objects-not-just-strings)**.

### Update:

In your case since you are already in a loop, don't set the value to a root element:

```
<select data-bind="options: Options, 
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   value: selectedOpt ">
</select>
```

Where `selectedOpt` needs to be an observable of your `confection`.

Check this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/rCJh5/)**

Comment: I thought so to, that this would work but it doesn't. If I do this all the selects in the loop would have the same value: $root.testtest! If I then put a subscrive on this or add a change event to the binding only the latest value is shown! Also for each option the function is triggerd:(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var text = $("#select option:selected").text(); // to select the text
```

//or

```
var value = $("#select option:selected").val(); // to select the value
```

Hope it helps.